# Drop-in compiler replacement can't find std crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to make a [drop-in compiler replacement](https://github.com/nrc/stupid-stats). Here's my source code.

```
#![feature(rustc_private)]
#![feature(link_args)]

extern crate rustc_driver;

fn main() {
    rustc_driver::set_sigpipe_handler();
    rustc_driver::main();
}
```

This is actually an exact copy of `rustc` source code.
I built, installed and exported this tool using an environment variable.

```
cargo install
export RUSTC=tool1    # `tool1` is name of binary
```

And I tried to build another project `example1`.
Here's source code of `example1`.

```
fn main() {}
```

Build failed with an error.

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: Could not compile `foo2`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I confirmed `example1` got built well with normal `cargo`. It gets broken only with `tool1`. (`export RUSTC=tool1`) If I `unset RUSTC`, it works again.

It seems I made some fault, but I can't figure out what. How can I make it work?

---

Here're my tool informations.

```
rustc -V
rustc 1.28.0-nightly (a1d4a9503 2018-05-20)

cargo -V
cargo 1.28.0-nightly (f352115d5 2018-05-15)
```

[Here's full example source code](https://github.com/eonil/rust-drop-in-replacement-fail).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspecting `tool1` shared libraries requirements reveals that the system can not locate Rust shared libraries (I'm on a Linux system so I use `ldd`):

```
> ldd /home/adona/.cargo/bin/tool1
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffed5938000)
    librustc_driver-aabc67f1ff8e0e97.so => not found
    libstd-46fff00efefae8a8.so => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa2d6f54000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa2d7521000)
```

Set `RUSTFLAGS` with the `-L` option if you want build through `cargo`, for example:

```
export RUSTFLAGS="-L $HOME/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib"
```

If you want use `tool1` directly from command line you have to configure the linker library path with `ldconfig` command or with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works! And just a note for macOS. Use `otool -L` instead of `ldd`. Library files are supposed to be at `$HOME/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib`.

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess here, but I think your `tool1` is not installed in the same folder as `rustc`. Note that you may have an executable called `rustc` in your cargo bin folder alongside your `tool1`, but this `rustc` is probably a `rustup` wrapper that redirects to the real compiler somewhere in your toolchain folder (probably `$HOME/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc`).

You will need to either install your `tool1` inside the toolchain folder or call it with a `-L` argument pointing to the toolchain libraries (probably `$HOME/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib`).